# git push origin develop does nothing

Tags: git

I'm new to using git.  I tried doing `git push origin develop` and the terminal says everything is up to date.  I tried `git diff --stat origin/develop` and the terminal displays:

```
 tpl/view/css/layout.css           |    7 ++++---
 tpl/view/ctrl.time-sheet-item.tpl |   10 +++++-----
 tpl/view/ctrl.time-sheet.tpl      |    7 +++----
 3 files changed, 12 insertions(+), 12 deletions(-)
```

So to me, it looks like there should still be files to push.  I went to my friend's computer and did a `git pull origin develop`, and it didn't receive the new changes to the three files I mentioned above.  How do I push my changes to the develop branch and receive them on another computer?

Comment: have you rebased your branch with develop?

Try doing git fetch
git rebase origin/develop
git push origin develop
and see if that fixes it

Comment: Have you commited your changes? `git commit`

Comment: @AbrahamP  I tried typing ` git rebase origin/develop`, but terminals says `fatal: Needed a single revision` followed by `invalid upstream origin/develop`

Comment: @SimonBoudrias Yes, i added and committed files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based off your comment the issue is (probably) that you branched repeatedly. (so like bar/develop, foo/bar/develop/ blah/foo/bar/develop, etc).

The reason your rebase is shooting you down is that you can't rebase to a branch that doesn't contain the initial commit you branched from ( fatal: Needed a single revision)

Do the following:

```
 git status
```

This will print your current branch. (Lets assume its blah/foo/bar/develop)

From here you have to options.

Option 1) Simpler, might not work if one of the intermediate steps has changed and you want things from it:

```
 git checkout develop
 git fetch
 git rebase origin/develop
 git merge origin/blah/foo/bar/develop
```

Option 2) Will work but could be very timeconsuming

```
 git fetch
 git rebase origin/foo/bar/develop
 git push origin foo/bar/develop
 git checkout foo/bar/develop
 git rebase origin/bar/develop
 git push origin bar/develop
 git checkout bar/develop
 git rebase origin/develop
```

I would probably try option 1 and only fall back to option 2 if option 1 doesn't work
In either case, solve the merge conflicts if any and you're done:

```
 git commit -a
 git push origin develop
```

Answer (score 2):

1. you should do "git add file1 file2 ..." to add your changes
2. you should do "git commit" to commit your changes to your local git repository
3. then you can push what you did to the remote repository.

Comment: Can you expand your answer? It is rather terse. If you could explain _why_ it doesn't work that'd help rather than just _what_. "Teach a man to fish..." and all that.